# Were the UNRWA cuts accompanied with some other form of financial commitment to other aid organizations or other policies to help Gazans?

Tags: international, united-nations, palestine, gaza

> As aid organizations, we are deeply concerned and outraged that some
> of the largest donors have united to suspend funding for the United
> Nations Relief and Works Agency (UNRWA), the main aid provider for
> millions of Palestinians in Gaza and the region. This comes amid a
> rapidly worsening humanitarian catastrophe in Gaza.
>
> The suspension of funding by donor states will impact life-saving
> assistance for over two million civilians, over half of whom are
> children, who rely on UNRWA aid in Gaza. The population faces
> starvation, looming famine and an outbreak of disease under Israel’s
> continued indiscriminate bombardment and deliberate deprivation of aid
> in Gaza.

https://www.unrwa.org/newsroom/official-statements/norwegian-refugee-council-joint-statement-unrwa-funding-cuts-threaten

Were the UNRWA cuts accompanied with some other form of financial commitment to other aid organizations or other policies to help Gazans? After it was found that some UNRWA members aided the terrorist attacks against Israel last year, several donors decided to suspend funding for UNRWA, but were those cuts accompanied with other policies to keep the flow of life-saving assistance into Gaza?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somewhat, [in the case of Germany](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/en/newsroom/news/-/2641762), at least

> Germany, in agreement with other donor countries, will temporarily not approve any further funding for UNRWA in Gaza until the matter is resolved – there are in any case no new funding decisions pending. Humanitarian assistance will continue. Just a few days ago, we increased our funding for the International Committee of the Red Cross and for UNICEF by 7 million euro.

TBH, even the US administration has implicitly somewhat downplayed the UNRWA funding suspension, when e.g Blinken [says](https://www.dw.com/en/blinken-urges-unrwa-to-immediately-probe-allegations/a-68117212) that UNRWA has an "absolutely indispensable" role in Gaza, which makes me think that they're not that actively looking for a wholesale replacement, right now. One anonymous Israeli official [concurred](https://www.timesofisrael.com/we-oppose-axing-unrwa-mid-war-senior-israeli-official-says-amid-global-funding-halt/) in re the short term, but the Israeli government does want UNRWA gone [together with Hamas], eventually.